# Unreachable code error when I use a break in my switch statement

Tags: javascript, redux

I am wondering what I am doing wrong in my code.  I am trying to do the following:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.ADD_TO_FAVORITES:
      if (state.faves.length <= 10) {
        return assign({}, state, {
          faves: state.faves.concat(action.payload),
          full: false
        });
      } else {
        return assign({}, state, {
          faves: state.faves,
          full: true
        });
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

My linter says to add a break before `default` case, but when I do that, it says `unreachable code`.

Comment: Don't return from a switch statement

Comment: @TinyGiant Why not?

Answer (score 6):

The linter rule i.e. 'no-fallthrough' in eslint, acts as to not allow any accidental fallthrough from case to case.

Meaning without break code execution will continue from matching case to next cases unless a break, return etc is encountered.

Sometimes we do need this but unintentional fallthrough can happen and this rule tries to prevent that.

You can disable the rule or configure it as warning . 
I would recommend to have a variable assigned for return value and at the end of the function and return it without disabling the rule.

```
function() {
var returnvalue;
Switch(variableA) {
    Case 1:
        returnvalue = somevalue;
        break;
    case 2:
        returnvalue = some other value;
        break;
     default:
         returnvalue= default value;
    }
return returnvalue;
```

}

And for the unreachable part, you are returning from your if else block.

So the break will never get any chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (action.type) {
case TYPES.ADD_TO_FAVORITES:
  if (state.faves.length <= 10) {
    return ...;
  } else {
    return ...;
  }
  break; // YOU HAVE ADDED BREAK HERE
default:
  return state;
}
```

Inside `case TYPES.ADD_TO_FAVORITES`, either `if` or `else` will be executed. As in both if and `else` you have returned some object, the `break` you have added  just before `default`, will never going to be executed!

That's why it says it says `unreachable code`.

Answer (score -4):

**Return** in **switch statement** make **no sense** and **not allowed**. You can only **return** in a **function**. If you want to get value back from switch statement. Just assign it to a variable like this

```
var result;
switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.ADD_TO_FAVORITES:
        if (state.faves.length <= 10) {
            result = assign({}, state, {
                faves: state.faves.concat(action.payload),
                full: false
            });
        } else {
            result = assign({}, state, {
                faves: state.faves,
                full: true
            });
        }
        break;
    default:
        result = state;
        break;
}
```

Comment: i am learning redux and they are using return in switch :(  here's an example : http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/

Comment: I don't now what is redux. But with your given information which is all about vanilla javascript, i can only have this answer.